# Multiple OR conditions in time difference

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a script that send me mail whith the content of what I've enterd in a form some days after the form is submitted. As a help for students to study. In the form enter what to study, then 1 day, 7 days and 28 days later get that in a mail.

I've made a form that collect time, recipient adress, subject and body for the mail. These are saved in a Google spreadsheet.

The code kind of work. But it send all of the mail from my test input in the sheet. I've added one 6 days ago, one yesterday and one today.
Today I should only get one mail and tomorrow two. But I get all of them today.

I think it's this line:

> ```
> if (diffDays == 1 || diffDays == 7 || diffDays == 28) continue;
> ```

I've trided to change it, searched other ways of writing it, as array for example.

Here's the full code:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('reminder')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(16) // Change time of day here
      .inTimezone("Europe/Stockholm")
      .create();
}

function reminder() {
  var today = new Date(); // Today
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var headerRows = 1;

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
    var row = data[i];
    var time = row[0];
    // Get time difference
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - time.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil((timeDiff) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)-1); 
    if (diffDays == 1 || diffDays == 7 || diffDays == 28) continue;
    var recipient = row[1];
    var subject = row[2];
    var body = row[3];

    // Send mail
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to execute the code only when your if statement is true.

Include all code after if statement in the statement itself, only executing it when diffDays = 1, 2 or 28.

```
function reminder() {
  var today = new Date(); // Today
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var headerRows = 1;

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
    var row = data[i];
    var time = row[0];
    // Get time difference
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - time.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil((timeDiff) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)-1); 
    if (diffDays == 1 || diffDays == 7 || diffDays == 28) {
      var recipient = row[1];
      var subject = row[2];
      var body = row[3];

      // Send mail
      GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested something similar, but then I did more changes at the same time and it would not work as it should. But will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: This works well! Thank you again. I tried this, but as I said, I made other changes that bore me thinking that this solution did not work.
Now I will only make it send emails based on date instead of time. Noticed that the code was sensitive to if the reported time was before or after the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `continue` means "stop processing this iteration of whatever loop is getting executed, and begin the next iteration." So your script sends reminders on every day *except* the days you want to remind them.

Changing your test to an "AND NOT", moving the code for reminding inside the existing check, or using a more expressive syntax like `switch` will satisfy your intent.

```
    switch (diffDays) {
      case 1:
      case 7:
      case 28:
        sendReminder(your, Args, Here);
        break;
      case 0:
        sendWelcome(some, other, Args);
        break;
      ...
      default:
        break;
    }
...
function sendReminder(your, Args, Here) {
  /* Code that uses function arguments to build and send an email */
}
```

"And not" meaning `if (diffDay != 1 && diffDay != ...)`, i.e. "if it's not this, and not that, and not this other thing, and not..."

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies a lot! The code seems a bit advanced for me right now, but I'll try if I solve it tomorrow.